# Likelihood: Possibility/Profit (Context based question)

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Officials were asked to examine the **likelihood** of providing banking facilities in the area.

My book gave the below options to choose one from:
1. Probability
2. Possibility
3. Profit
4. no improvement

We have to compare the Bold part with the expressions formed by using (1),(2) and (3) and we need to choose an expression which is an improvement upon the bold part.

I am thinking it should be '2' but my book gave '3' as the answer. 
Please put your thoughts here. TIA.

Comment: Are the word choices intended to replace "likelihood" without changing the meaning? Or to explain the intent of the phrase?

Comment: We have to compare the Bold part with the expressions formed by using (1),(2) and (3) and we need to choose an expression which is an improvement upon the bold part.

Comment: I would add this information to the question.

Answer (score 2):

*likelihood* is basically the same as *possibility* in this context, so I would not call it an improvement.

I imagine the condition of "providing banking facilities" would be that they would make a profit. However the word to substitute would be *profitability*.

> Officials were asked to examine the **profitability** of providing banking facilities in the area.